# Is it possible to write time derivatives with the dot notation?

Tags: output-formatting, latex, custom-notation

In physics, we often write time derivatives with a dot ($\dot{a}$, $\ddot{a}$, for example).

Is it possible to force *Mathematica* to use this notation and then apply `TeXForm` so I can easily copy&paste my results in a TeX file?

If needed, I run *Mathematica 10* on a Windows 8.1, 64 bits machine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I can't test robustness, because I don't know what your work flow is, but one can `Format` the expression:

```
Format[D[f_[t], {t, n_ /; n < 3}]] := OverDot[f, n]
```

Then,

```
expr1 = D[f[t], t]
expr2 = D[f[t], {t, 2}]
```

looks like:

[image]

Then, you can use `TeXForm`:

```
TeXForm[expr1 + expr2]
(* \ddot{f}+\dot{f} *)
```